# Check if user is authorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization, windows-authentication

I need to be able to determine if a user is **authorized** (not authenticated) in my ASP.net MVC 3 application.

I have an intranet application that uses Windows Authentication to authenticate users. Only users within the "allowedUsers" group are allowed access to the site and this is enforced with the `AuthorizeAttribute` like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles="allowedUsers")]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
```

This works as expected and any users not in the group are not provided access to the site. So far, so good.

However I now have a problem in cases where users are authenticated but not authorized. Allow me to explain:

In my `BaseController` I override the `Initialize` method. Here I set up my domain service with any dependencies it requires from the controller, one of which is the `User.Identity` object.

```
Service.Initialize(User.Identity);
```

Inside my service I use the `Identity.Name` to look up the users details from my database. My service was designed under the assumption that if the user has gotten this far, they must be an authorized user, so if no record matches I assume they are a new (but authorized) user and create a new user record using the `Identity.Name` supplied ready for them to enter the rest of their details later.

The problem comes in situations where the user is authenticated but not authorised; in this case the user is denied access to the page but the controller is still instantiated behind the scenes and the service initialised. The service will never find a match in the database (because the user shouldn't have access) and creates a new user record. This leaves me with a load of records for users that should not have access (with only the `Identity.Name` filled in).

My first (naive) attempt to fix this was to check the `Identity.IsAuthenticated` property in my service, however, after much research I have learnt the difference between authentication and authorization and understand why this is insufficient as it is possible for a user to be authenticated but not authorised.

So what I am basically looking for is something similar to `User.IsAuthenticated` but for authorisation E.G. `User.IsAuthorised`. The idea is that I will check this in my controller and if the user is not authorised I won't initialise the service.

Is there any way of determining this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to think of this problem not in terms of authentication or authorisation but in terms of the MVC pipeline.

My problem came from the fact that I was initialising my service in the `Initialize` method of the `Controller` which seems to be called even if the user is not authorised. This made it clear to me that the initialisation of my service needed to take place as late as possible in the lifetime of the controller prior to any action methods being called.

I moved the service initialisation logic into the `OnActionExecuting` method *prior* to the base implementation (so that my service is initialised before the action method is executed).
The MVC pipeline will only call this method if the user is both authorized and authenticated giving me the desired behaviour.